# Webpack require files from specific sub-directories

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack, require

Here's my folder structure

```
- componentA
  - specs
     - file1.js
     - file2.js
 - componentB
  - specs
     - file1.js
     - file2.js
```

I want to require each file under each specs dir from both componentA and B.
How would the regex look like?

something like: require(**/specs/*.js) ?

Comment: Give this a try [`component[AB]\/specs\/.*\.js`](https://regex101.com/r/EOZ5yg/2)

Comment: @Gurman thanks for the response. The thing is the structure was just sample and my folders have different names like modules, auth, profile etc. is there something generic that can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this fixed it for me:

```
/.*\/specs\/.*\.js/
```